# Can the iPhone 7 Plus battery be damaged by the use of an external battery charger?

Tags: battery, charging, charger, iphone

When I bought the iPhone 7 Plus, I also bought a Mophie External Battery Charger, the Powerstation 2, I haven't used yet, so far the iPhone battery lasts long enough for me, but I read on an article that external battery chargers are one of the reasons cellphones' batteries get damaged. Is this true, or it's only with certain chargers?

Comment: Please add a link (or better yet, the relevant section) of the article you read.

Comment: Seems unlikely that the article you read was accurate. The battery charge is managed by the iPhone itself. For phones where the battery is removable, it is possible that unsuitable external chargers could incorrectly charge the removed battery.

Answer (score 1):

I bought and used an external battery charger on mu iPhone 5s and believe that it did damage my phone's battery. I now get only a few hours of power before the phone is depleted. This happened directly after using the charger for a week.